# Need I make all classes immutable?

Tags: java, immutability, effective-java

I read Effective Java, and there written

> If a class cannot be made immutable, limit its mutability as much as
> possible...

and

> ...make every field final unless there is a compelling reason to make it
> nonfinal.

So need I always make all my POJO(for example simple `Book`class with `ID`, `Title` and `Author` fields) classes immutable? And when I want to change state of my object(for example user change it in table where represented many Books), instead of setters use method like this:

```
public Book changeAuthor(String author) {
   return new Book(this.id, this.title, author);  //Book constructor is private
}
```

But I think is really not a good idea..

Please, explain me when to make a class immutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need always to make your POJO immutable. Like you said, sometimes it can be a bad idea. If you object has attributes that will change over the time, a setter is the most comfortable way to do it.

But you should consider to make your object immutable. It will help you to find errors, to program more clearly and to deal with concurrency.

But I think you quoting say everything:

> If a class cannot be made immutable, limit its mutability as much as
>   possible...

and

> ...make every field final unless there is a compelling reason to make
>   it nonfinal.

That's what you should do. Unless it's not possible, because you have a setter. But then be aware of concurrency.

Comment: +1 Sometimes a field has to be mutable or immutable, when it can be either, try to make it immutable. e.g. make fields `final` when you can.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** A `POJO` is one which has `private Instance Variables` with `Getter` and `Setter` **methods.**

**2.** And Classes like `String class`, which needs a **constant** `behavior/implementation` at **all time needs to be
      final**, not the one which needs to change with time.

**3.** For making a **class immutable, final is not only the solution**, One can have `private Instance variables`, with only `Getter methods`. And **their state being set into the** `Constructor`.

**4.** Now depending on your coding decision, try to rectify which **fields needs to be constant throughout the program**, if you feel that certain fields are to be `immutable`, make them final.

**5. JVM** uses a mechanism called **Constant folding** for **pre-calculating** the constant values.

Comment: I think you're conflating POJO with Bean. A POJO doesn't necessarily have Getters and Setters. A Bean may or may not be a POJO, a POJO may or may not be a Bean. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object

Comment: @Grundlefleck well i reviewed the link you have mentioned, and i found this..  The definition of the POJO can be as follows:

`public class MyBean {
 
    private String someProperty;
 
    public String getSomeProperty() {
         return someProperty;
    }
 
    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}` So its the private variable with getter and setter, fine...from javaranch.com i found this `Java Bean and POJO are more or less same. POJO are Plain Old Java Objects, also known as entity class. Java Beans are again the same only`

Comment: That is in the context describing an example of a specific type of POJO, a Bean. The definition `a POJO is a Java object not bound by any restriction other than those forced by the Java Language Specification` is probably most concise and accurate. For me, at least, that would include structural restrictions (public methods prefixed with {get|set}) as restricted to by the Bean spec.

Comment: Java doesnt force you to use one of the Encapsulation funda of private var, and getter/setter... its just the proper way to do it.. Now, as you said `its specific type Pojo`, but still its a pojo.....

Comment: that's fine, a Bean *can* be a POJO. but I don't agree it's correct that a POJO *must* have private instance variables with Getters and Setters.

Comment: I can again argue on this by providing another example or defination from some other site, but then its endless, I think the @MyTitle already got his answer, and it was not abt Pojo or Bean, but about using final.... but still i am obliged as you shared your insight with all of us

Answer (score 1):

In OOP world we have **state**. State it's all properties in your object. Return new object when you change state of your object guaranties that your application will work correctly in concurrent environment without specific things (synchronized, locks, atomics, etc.). But you **always** create new object.

Imagine that your object contains 100 properties, or to be real some collection with 100 elements. To follow the idea of immutability you need copy this collection as well. It's great memory overhead, perhaps it handled by GC. In most situation it's better to manually handle state of object than make object immutable. In some hard cases better to return copy if concurrent problems very hard. It depends on task. No silver bullet.